# Lean to free standing patio cover

Tags: wood, patio, post

I am building a 12'x 20' free standing lean to off the back of the house. I am planning on using 4"x4" posts with a 4"x6" beam across the back and front, with a 4"x6" beam across the sides with 2"x6" for the roof with clear sheeting for roof. My question is- how far apart should my 4"x4" posts be~ I am hoping to have the sides open- with the front and back posts 10" apart. Is this enough support?
Thank you,
Paul

Comment: So what is the snow load? Wind load? This is not a question with a "one-size fits all" answer. If you want a useful answer, provide enough details so somone can write that, in your question. [Edit] them in. You might also take the [tour] and review how to ask a good question, in there.

Comment: *how far apart should my 4"x4" posts be* is why I use 6x6s and 2x12s, because (then it doesn't look like some adhoc crap made out of 4x4s...) the answer to that question is w/e length of lumber you can buy and it doesn't need bracing in the corners because it'll have two, 5/8ths minimum, SS through bolts, per post, spaced ~10" apart.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/117580/23295 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/63826/23295 "pay special attention to the *minimum edge distance*" on a 4x4.... means you only get one.

Comment: Do you want it to last 80y or less than 10?